# Why my regex is not working ? [Java] [Regex] [Whitespaceproblem]

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I defined a regex to accept mobile number.

For example: `90 9121312333`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UserRegistrationProblem 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Mobile Number");
    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mobile = sc.next();
    
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{10}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mobile);
    
        if (matcher.matches())
        {
            System.out.println("Valid Mobile Number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Mobile Number");
        }
    }
}
```

So, it's not working.

There is some kind of problem with the whitespace.

I looked for the syntax and it's correct.

Comment: Try printing `System.out.println(mobile);` before trying the regex.

Comment: Print the length of your string in the console too, to make sure no whitelines are hiding somewhere in there.

Comment: https://ideone.com/pVVXFv makes the issue obvious (as stepping through your code in a debugger before asking here also would have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sc.next()` is only reading `"90"`.
To check it, add `System.out.println(">" + mobile + "<");` after reading the number.
Even better, at least in case of error, show the user what caused it:

```
System.out.println("Invalid Mobile Number: \"" + mobile + "\"");
```

this will help the user (and eventually the developer!)

Documentation:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.
>
> **next()**:Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

you probably want to use `nextLine()` to read the whole input

---

Note: no need to use `^` and `$` when using `Matcher.matches()` - this always test if the full input matches the expression (not true for `Matcher.find()`).